# Netezza alter column constraint

Tags: sql, constraints, netezza, alter-table

As of Netezza version 7.2 is there still no other way to change column constraint NOT NULL to NULL and back again without creating a new table and droping the old one? Seems a very brutal way to change column constraint for very large tables.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, that is not the only way, as you can add and rename columns, so you could do something like this:

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create table test1 (col1 integer not null);
CREATE TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> alter table test1 add column (col2 integer);
ALTER TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> update test1 set col2=col1;
UPDATE 0
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> alter table test1 drop column col1 cascade;
ALTER TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> alter table test1 rename column col2 to col1;
ALTER TABLE
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> groom table test1 versions;
NOTICE:  Groom will not purge records deleted by transactions that started after 2016-09-29 12:38:13.
NOTICE:  If this process is interrupted please either repeat GROOM VERSIONS or issue 'GENERATE STATISTICS ON "TEST1"'
NOTICE:  Groom processed 0 pages; purged 0 records; scan size unchanged; table size unchanged.
GROOM VERSIONS
```

However, that's not any less "brutal" in terms of I/O. Day-to-day Netezza life so often involves CTAS of large tables. And with that you could more simply just solve this, as you would have to do if you were changing the distribution column.